# SQL selecting values between two columns with a list

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm attempting to find rows given a list of values where one of the values is in a range between two of the columns, as an example:

```
id     column1    column2
1      1          5
2      6          10
3      11         15
4      16         20
5      21         25
...
99     491        495
100    496        500
```

I'd like to give a list of values, e.g. `(23, 83, 432, 334, 344)` which would return the rows

```
id     column1    column2
5      21         25
17     81         85
87     431        435
67     331        335
69     341        345
```

The only way I can think of doing this so far has been to split each into it's own call by doing

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE (column1 < num1 AND num1 < column2)
```

However this scales quite poorly when the list of numbers is around several million.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting millions of numbers into the SQL command itself would be unwieldy.

Obviously, you have to put the numbers into a (temporary) table.
Then you can just join the two tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA JOIN TempTable
  ON TempTable.Value BETWEEN TableA.column1 AND TableA.column2;
```

Comment: For an example using 53 numbers, I've noticed that the BETWEEN statement takes 13 seconds to finish, however, using `WHERE column1 <= num1 ORDER BY column1 DESC LIMIT 1` only took 0.0289 seconds. Do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: Because comparing *two* columns is something different, and cannot be optimized completely with an index.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to modify your answer so that it works with `WHERE column1 <= num1 ORDER BY column1 DESC LIMIT 1` and produces the same results?

Comment: No; as I said, *two* values are not the same as *one* value, regardless of how you write the comparison.

Comment: This solved an issue I had in a query that was making use of a scalar function to get the required result.  You can image how long that was taking...  This implementation:  super-fast.